# solving recurrence relation by using iterations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I got for homework the following recurrence relation:
$T(n)=n^\frac{2}{3}\cdot T(n^\frac{1}{3})+c  $

and $T(1)=O(1)  $
$\forall n\leq2 $

And this is what I got so far:

by using the iterative method I got that the for any $k$ :

$T(n)=n^{1-\frac{1}{3^k}}\cdot T(n^\frac{1}{3^{k+1}})+c+cn^\frac{2}{3}+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}}+...+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+...+\frac{2}{3^{k-1}}}  $

and the maximum level of the tree is for $k=log_3(log_2(n))$
then for $k=log_3(log_2(n))$ :

$T(n)=n^{1-\frac{1}{3^{log_3(log_2(n))}}}\cdot T(2)+c+cn^\frac{2}{3}+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}}+...+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+...+\frac{2}{3^{log_3(log_2(n))-1}}}  $

$T(n)=n^{1-\frac{1}{log_2(n)}}+c+cn^\frac{2}{3}+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}}+...+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+...+\frac{2}{3^{log_3(log_2(n))-1}}}  $

and
$n^{1-\frac{1}{log_2(n)}}=\frac{n}{2}$

so,I get :

$T(n)=\frac{n}{2}+c+cn^\frac{2}{3}+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}}+...+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+...+\frac{2}{3^{log_3(log_2(n))-1}}}  $

also the sum in the power of the last element is :
$\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+...+\frac{2}{3^(log_3(log_2(n))-1)}=1-\frac{1}{log_2(n)} $

so, the last element is also equal to $\frac{n}{2}$
so far I got :

$T(n)=\frac{n}{2}+c+cn^\frac{2}{3}+cn^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}}+...+c\frac{n}{2} $

how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

With $n>0$ we have

$$
\frac{T(n)}{n} = \frac{T(n^{\frac 13})}{n^{\frac 13}}+\frac cn
$$

Calling $R(n) = \frac{T(n)}{n}$ we follow with

$$
R(n) = R(n^{\frac 13})+\frac cn
$$

now with $\mathcal{R}(\cdot) = R\left(3^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_3 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{R}(z) = \mathcal{R}\left(\frac z3\right) + c 3^{-z}
$$

now with $z = 3^u$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{R}\left(3^u\right) = \mathcal{R}\left(3^{u-1}\right) + c 3^{-3^u}
$$

Calling now $\mathbb{R}\left(\cdot\right) = \mathcal{R}\left(3^{(\cdot)}\right)$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{R}\left(u\right) = \mathbb{R}\left(u-1\right) + c 3^{-3^u}
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb{R}\left(u\right) =c \left(c_0+\sum_{k=1}^{k=u}3^{-3^k}\right)
$$

now, going backwards with $u = \log_3 z$ and $z = \log_3 n$ we get at

$$
T(n) = c \cdot n\left(c_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\log_3(\log_3 n)}3^{-3^k}\right)
$$

Remember that $3^{-3^{\log_3(\log_3 n)}} = n^{-\frac 13}$ thus if $n = 3^{3^3}$ we have

$$
T(3^{3^3})= c\cdot 3^{3^3} \left(c_0+\sum_{k=1}^{3}3^{-3^k}\right) = c(7625597484987 c_0 + 282816956971)
$$